# How to get coefficient of the discrete fourier Series from the fourier transform

Tags: discrete-signals, signal-analysis, fourier-transform, fourier-series

Given $X(v)$ the Discrete Fourier transform of a discrete periodic signal $x(n)$, it's possible to arrive to the $c_k$ of the Fourier series $$x(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k \exp(2\pi i k t) $$  directly?

Comment: um, write down the formula of the IDFT directly below your formula, i.e. how $x(n)$ can be calculated from $X(k)$. What do you notice?

Comment: what's the IDFT ? @MarcusMüller

Comment: The inverse discrete Fourier transform; wikipedia!